# Python - handling htmlparser data with handle_starttag and handle_endtag

Tags: python, html-parsing

I'm trying to control `handle_data`, based on a given limitation to `handle_starttag` and `endtag`, however, I am not able to achieve this.

I have also used flags set to `True` and `False` to achieve this, but no control on data and tags is happening.

Here is my code:

```py
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.htmlList = []
        self.flag = False

    def handle_starttag(self,tag,attrs):

        if  tag.lower() in ['a','title'] and tag.lower() != 'script':
            self.flag = True

    def handle_data(self, data):

        if self.flag == True:
            words = data.split()
            for i in words:
                if i.isalpha() ==  True:  
                    self.htmlList.append(i)
            return (self.htmlList)
```